# Wish for future

Tags: grammar

I am a student and preparing for my examination. Supposing that I am going to sit the examination in two months time and the result will be announced in six months time. I want myself to pass the examination with good marks. This is a future wish. Which of the following should I use?

---

a. I wish I passed the examination with A grade.

---

b. I hope I pass the examination with A grade.

Note that result is not in my hand. I only can work hard to get good result. And, good result is howsoever possible but not certain.

Secondly, how would we differentiate between 'I wish' and 'I hope' when we talk about future.

Answer (score -1):

Wish gives the perception that the task you want to achieve is impossible, ergo I'd go with hope. There is always hope, but wishes are usually considered mystical (largely unreal to many). Now, to differentiate between the two in regards to the future. Personally, I believe wish is for my distant or physically inconceivable goals, whereas hope is more realistic and closer in time.